# There is an issue in the deselection process that adds unwanted partition lines during the deselection of the selected area of the image

Tags: javascript, jcrop, coords, deselect, imageareaselect

[image: here is the image with issue]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Select Areas Demo
    
    
        .jcrop-selection {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
            /* Yellow highlight for the selection */
            border: 1px dashed #999;
        }

```
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
```

Save Selected Areas
    Toggle Deselect Mode

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var jcropApi;
        var selectedAreas = []; // Array to store selected areas
        var deselectModeActive = false; // Flag to indicate deselect mode

        // Initialize Jcrop with multi-selection enabled
        jQuery('#selectableImage').Jcrop({
            multi: true,
            onSelect: function (coords) {
                // Handle selection based on deselect mode
                if (deselectModeActive) {
                    removePart(coords);
                } else {
                    selectedAreas.push(coords);
                    console.log('Selected areas:', selectedAreas);
                    drawOverlay(coords);
                }
            }
        }, function () {
            jcropApi = this;
        });

        // Save selected areas when the button is clicked
        jQuery('#saveAreas').on('click', function () {
            // Check if any area is selected
            if (selectedAreas.length === 0) {
                alert('No areas selected!');
                return;
            }

            // Create an array to store base64 strings and area information for each area
            var dataToSend = [];
            var mainImage = jQuery('#selectableImage').attr('src').split('/').pop();

            // Process each selected area
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedAreas.length; i++) {
                var area = selectedAreas[i];

                // Create a new canvas for each selected area
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Load the image
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = jQuery('#selectableImage').attr('src');

                // Set canvas dimensions to match the selected area
                canvas.width = area.w;
                canvas.height = area.h;

                // Draw the selected area on the canvas
                ctx.drawImage(image, area.x, area.y, area.w, area.h, 0, 0, area.w, area.h);

                // Convert canvas content to base64 string
                var base64String = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

                // Store base64 string and area information in an object
                var areaData = {
                    base64String: base64String,
                    area: area,
                    mainImg: mainImage
                };

                // Push the object to the data array
                dataToSend.push(areaData);
            }

            // Send all base64 strings and area information to the server
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/snap-news/save.php',
                contentType: 'application/json', // Set content type to JSON
                data: JSON.stringify({ areas: dataToSend }), // Convert data to JSON string
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('Selected areas saved successfully!');
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    alert('Error saving selected areas!');
                }
            });
        });

        // Toggle deselect mode when the button is clicked
        jQuery('#toggleDeselectMode').on('click', function () {
            deselectModeActive = !deselectModeActive;
            if (deselectModeActive) {
                alert('Deselect mode is ON. Click on selected areas to remove parts.');
            } else {
                alert('Deselect mode is OFF. Normal selection mode is active.');
            }
        });

        function drawOverlay(coords) {
            // Create a new div for the overlay
            var overlay = document.createElement('div');
            overlay.className = 'jcrop-selection';
            overlay.style.position = 'absolute';
            overlay.style.left = coords.x + 'px';
            overlay.style.top = coords.y + 'px';
            overlay.style.width = coords.w + 'px';
            overlay.style.height = coords.h + 'px';

            // Append the overlay to the container
            jQuery('#selectableImage').parent().append(overlay);
        }


        function removePart(coords) {
            // Remove part of the selected area in deselect mode
            var newAreas = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < selectedAreas.length; i++) {
                var area = selectedAreas[i];
                // Check if the clicked area intersects with any selected area
                if (isIntersecting(coords, area)) {
                    // Split the area into non-overlapping parts
                    var splitAreas = splitArea(area, coords);
                    // Add the non-overlapping parts to the new areas array
                    newAreas = newAreas.concat(splitAreas);
                } else {
                    // If there is no intersection, keep the area as it is
                    newAreas.push(area);
                }
            }

            // Update the selected areas array
            selectedAreas = newAreas;

            // Redraw the overlays
            jQuery('.jcrop-selection').remove();
            for (var j = 0; j < selectedAreas.length; j++) {
                drawOverlay(selectedAreas[j]);
            }
        }


        function isIntersecting(coords1, coords2) {
            // Check if two sets of coordinates are intersecting
            return (
                coords1.x < coords2.x + coords2.w &&
                coords1.x + coords1.w > coords2.x &&
                coords1.y < coords2.y + coords2.h &&
                coords1.y + coords1.h > coords2.y
            );
        }

        function splitArea(area, splitCoords) {
            // Split an area into non-overlapping parts based on another set of coordinates
            var splitAreas = [];

            // Check and add the left part
            if (splitCoords.x > area.x) {
                splitAreas.push({
                    x: area.x,
                    y: area.y,
                    w: splitCoords.x - area.x,
                    h: area.h
                });
            }

            // Check and add the right part
            if (splitCoords.x + splitCoords.w < area.x + area.w) {
                splitAreas.push({
                    x: splitCoords.x + splitCoords.w,
                    y: area.y,
                    w: area.x + area.w - splitCoords.x - splitCoords.w,
                    h: area.h
                });
            }

            // Check and add the top part
            if (splitCoords.y > area.y) {
                splitAreas.push({
                    x: Math.max(splitCoords.x, area.x),
                    y: area.y,
                    w: Math.min(splitCoords.x + splitCoords.w, area.x + area.w) - Math.max(splitCoords.x, area.x),
                    h: splitCoords.y - area.y
                });
            }

            // Check and add the bottom part
            if (splitCoords.y + splitCoords.h < area.y + area.h) {
                splitAreas.push({
                    x: Math.max(splitCoords.x, area.x),
                    y: splitCoords.y + splitCoords.h,
                    w: Math.min(splitCoords.x + splitCoords.w, area.x + area.w) - Math.max(splitCoords.x, area.x),
                    h: area.y + area.h - splitCoords.y - splitCoords.h
                });
            }

            return splitAreas;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I need to subtract the deselection portion from the selected area of the image. In the above code, I tried but there is an issue that when I deselect the portion on the selected area, it adds a partition line when updating the coordinates after removing the deselection area and saves one area with different parts, which I do not need. Please guide me on how to solve this issue.